# Toolbar Contribution not visible in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have a toolbar contribution consisting of a Label with an image,a text-Label and a context menu. I am extending `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` and basically do the following in the createControl:

```
   @Override
  protected Control createControl(final Composite parent) {
    // Create a composite to place the labels in
    Composite comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    // Give some room around the control
    RowLayout layout = new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.marginHeight = 2;
    layout.marginWidth = 2;
    comp.setLayout(layout);
    Label imageLabel = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    imageLabel.setImage(...);
    Label label = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText(...);
    return comp;
  }
```

The result is, that I can see that there is a contribution in the status bar, but it has a height of 0. I tried GridLayout with x/yHint, but that didn't help either. It worked fine in Eclipse Mars. I am using Eclipse on Windows 7 with JDK1.8.0-121. Any ideas, why the layout isn't properly applied in Eclipse Neon?

Comment: Did you try to set the LayoutData for your `Composite` as well?

Comment: yes, I did. Didn't paste that part though. Using GridLayoutFactory with defaults, extendedMargins according to https://github.com/ANCIT/eclipse-utils/blob/master/org.ancit.search.web/src/org/ancit/search/web/controlContributions/GoogleSearchControlContribution.java

Comment: Looks like Eclipse bug [471313](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471313)

Comment: isDynamic true along with the setRedraw call did the job. Even though I doubt this is a long term solution. Thank you, greg. You should have answered the question (instead of comment)